# How can I transform a PDF to get the same PDF but with four Pages on one?

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, printing

At my university we have a web service which allows us to upload PDF files and print them. Sometimes I want to print two or even four pages of the document on one page of the paper. As the online service doesn't allow me to choose this option (like Adobe Reader does), I have to change the PDF.

How can I change the PDF in this way (on a Ubuntu Linux machine)?

Comment: This is usually a function of the printer driver, not the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Go to File > Print
- Select `Print to File` with output type `PDF`
- On the page setup tab look for `Pages per side`
- Here select 4 and hit <kbd>print</kbd>.

This will create a new file with 4 pages on each page.

Comment: Thanks for this beautiful solution. I didn't look at "print to file" because I thought I would give me a postscript document. +1 and accept!

Answer (score 5):

For something fairly automated, you can use the PDFJam scripts for this. Info [here](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/).

For another option, with a GUI, check out [jpdftweak](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/)

I use another Linux distro, but I'm sure these are available for Ubuntu without too much trouble.